# Python - wrapper for nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, wrapper

I need a simple nested dictionary wrapper, and I tried something like this

```
class DictWrapper(object):

    def __init__(self, x_names, y_names):
        self._dict = {}
        for x in x_names:
            self._dict[x] = {}
            for y in y_names:
                self._dict[x][y] = {}

    def __setitem__(self, x, y, val):
        self._dict[x][y] = val

    def __getitem__(self, x, y):
        return self._dict[x][y]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    results_holder = DictWrapper(['x1', 'x2', 'x3'], ['y1', 'y2'])
    results_holder['x1']['y2'] = 11
```

However, that resulted in the following error:

```
   results_holder['x1']['y2'] = 11
TypeError: __getitem__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Am I on the right track? How can I make this sort of simple dictionary wrapper work?

Comment: here `self._dict[x][y] = {}` you say that `dict[x][y]` is a dict. `11` is not a dict. (although you should be able to set it to whatever, that's odd)

Comment: Do you need to specify the keys up-front?  Would a `defaultdict(dict)` work for you?

Comment: Is anything stopping you from using a non-nested dict? `results_holder = {}; results_holder['x1', 'y2'] = 11` works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution - single key

```
class DictWrapper(object):

    def __init__(self, x_names, y_names):
        self._dict = {}
        for x in x_names:
            self._dict[x] = {}
            for y in y_names:
                self._dict[x][y] = {}

    def __setitem__(self, key, val): # single key
        self._dict[key[0]][key[1]] = val

    def __getitem__(self, key): # single key
        return self._dict[key[0]][key[1]]


results_holder = DictWrapper(['x1', 'x2', 'x3'], ['y1', 'y2'])
results_holder[('x1','y2')] = 11
print results_holder[('x1','y2')]

# without () works too
results_holder['x1','y2'] = 11
print results_holder['x1','y2']
```

Answer (score -1):

Python dictionaries can already be nested.

You can already build the dictionnary the way you want with `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product

x = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3']
y = ['y1', 'y2']
results_holder = dict( # transform to dict
    product( # build the matrice
        x, [dict(product(y, [{}]))]
    ))
results_holder['x1']['y2'] = 11
```